When Flutter Hot Reload is installed, the application restarts
I'm developing an application with Flutter. But there is a problem. When I Hot Reload, the application starts from the beginning.
My main.dart:
void main() async {
  await setup();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeManager.instance),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> setup() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await HiveService.instance.init();
  await DioService.instance.init();
  await ThemeManager.instance.initTheme();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("started"); // started
    AppRouter _appRouter = AppRouter();
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: AppConstants.appName,
      themeMode: context.themeMode,
      theme: context.theme,
      darkTheme: context.theme,
      routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
      scaffoldMessengerKey: GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>(),
    );
  }
}

Splash View:
@RoutePage()
class SplashView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<SplashBloc, SplashState>(
      bloc: SplashBloc()..add(SplashCheckSkippedEvent(context: context)),
      onPageBuilder: (context, cubit, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: _containerDecoration(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TransferGoalLogo(
                  theme: LogoTheme.light,
                  width: context.dynamicWidth(0.8),
                ),
                context.emptySizedHeightNormal,
                const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration _containerDecoration() {
    return BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage(ImageConstants.instance.splashBackground),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        opacity: 0.5,
      ),
      gradient: const LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [
          Colors.black87,
          Colors.black54,
          Colors.black45,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

SplashBloc:
part 'splash_event.dart';
part 'splash_state.dart';

class SplashBloc extends Bloc<SplashEvent, SplashState> {
  SplashService splashService = SplashService();

  SplashBloc() : super(SplashInitialState()) {
    on<SplashCheckSkippedEvent>(_checkSkippedOnboard);
    on<SplashNavigateToLatestTransfersEvent>(_onNavigateToLatestTransfers);
    on<SplashNavigateToOnboardEvent>(_navigateToOnboard);
  }

  Future<void> _checkSkippedOnboard(SplashCheckSkippedEvent event, Emitter<SplashState> emit) async {
    final bool isSkipped = await splashService.checkSkippedOnboard();
    if (isSkipped) {
      add(SplashNavigateToLatestTransfersEvent(context: event.context));
    } else {
      add(SplashNavigateToOnboardEvent(context: event.context));
    }
  }

  void _navigateToOnboard(SplashNavigateToOnboardEvent event, Emitter<SplashState> emit) {
    NavigationHelper.pushAndRemoveUntil(event.context, route: const OnboardView());
  }

  void _onNavigateToLatestTransfers(SplashNavigateToLatestTransfersEvent event, Emitter<SplashState> emit) {
    NavigationHelper.pushAndRemoveUntil(event.context, route: LatestTransfersView());
  }
  
}

SplashEvent and State:
part of 'splash_bloc.dart';

sealed class SplashEvent extends Equatable {
  const SplashEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class SplashCheckSkippedEvent extends SplashEvent {
  final BuildContext context;

  const SplashCheckSkippedEvent({required this.context});
}

final class SplashNavigateToOnboardEvent extends SplashEvent {
  final BuildContext context;

  const SplashNavigateToOnboardEvent({required this.context});
}

final class SplashNavigateToLatestTransfersEvent extends SplashEvent {
  final BuildContext context;

  const SplashNavigateToLatestTransfersEvent({required this.context});
}

sealed class SplashState extends Equatable {
  const SplashState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class SplashInitialState extends SplashState {}

final class SplashLoadedState extends SplashState {}

final class SplashSkippedState extends SplashState {}

final class SplashNotSkippedState extends SplashState {}

and BaseView:
typedef WidgetBuilderCallback<C extends BlocBase<S>, S> = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, C cubit, S state);
typedef OnReadyCallback<C> = void Function(C cubit);

class BaseView<C extends BlocBase<S>, S> extends StatefulWidget {
  final WidgetBuilderCallback<C, S> onPageBuilder;
  final OnReadyCallback<C>? onReady;
  final C? cubit;
  final BlocBase<S>? bloc;

  const BaseView({
    super.key,
    required this.onPageBuilder,
    this.onReady,
    this.cubit,
    this.bloc,
  }) : assert(cubit != null || bloc != null, 'Cubit or Bloc must be provided');

  @override
  State<BaseView<C, S>> createState() => _BaseViewState<C, S>();
}

class _BaseViewState<C extends BlocBase<S>, S> extends State<BaseView<C, S>> {
  late final C _cubit;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.cubit != null) {
      _cubit = widget.cubit!;
      widget.onReady?.call(_cubit);
    } else {
      _cubit = widget.bloc as C;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cubit.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<C>(
      create: (context) => _cubit,
      child: BlocBuilder<C, S>(
        builder: (context, state) => widget.onPageBuilder(context, _cubit, state),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How can I solve this problem? I developing with iOS and Android. I looked at other support topics on the internet but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for help.

What platform?  Web, for example, has no "hot reload", only a "hot restart".

@RandalSchwartz sorry I forgot say. I develop with iOS and Android.
